# Spring AOP and annotation to check parameter before method execution

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, spring-aop

I have to throw an exception if a method parameter is a particular value.
The aim is to lock all the method that work with the specific value so I thought to use Spring AOP but I am new with it.
My problem is retrieve the value of method parameter, I create this sample:

Annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAOPAnnotation {
}
```

AOP class

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TestAOP {

    @Before("@annotation(TestAOPAnnotation)")
    public void logAOP(){
        //Make some operations with database and throw exception in a specific case 
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

The method where I use the annotation

```
@Override
@TestAOPAnnotation
public List<Animals> findByName(String name) throws QueryException {
    try{
        return animalsRepository.findByName(name);
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new QueryException(e);
    }
}
```

and where I catch the exception

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/test/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Animals> findByName(@PathVariable String name){
    try{
        return databaseAnimalsServices.findByName(name);
    }catch(QueryException e){
        return null;
    }catch(Exception e){
        //CATCH AOP EXCEPTION
        List<Animals> list = new ArrayList<Animals>();
        list.add(new Animals("AOP", "exception", "test"));
        return list;
    }
}
```

How can I get the name parameter? I may use another annotation on parameter (or only this annotation) but I don't know how. Can you help me?

**EDIT**
To catch parameter annotation I may use:

```
@Before("execution(* *(@Param (*),..))")
```

but it works only if I know the parameters order instead I need only the annotated parameter.
Otherwise , until now, the best solution is

```
@Before("@annotation(TestAOPAnnotation) && args(name,..)")
public void logAOP(String name){
    System.out.println(name);
    throw new RuntimeException("error");
}
```

but the parameter must be the fist in the signature

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `@Around` advice which has access to the invocation data.

```
@Around("@annotation(TestAOPAnnotation)")
public Object logAOP(ProceedingJoinPoint aPoint) throws Throwable {
    // First, implement your checking logic
    // aPoint.getArgs() may be inspected here ...
    if (...) {
        throw new RuntimeException(...);
    }

    // now, actually proceed with the method call
    return aPoint.proceed();
}
```

`getArgs()` gives you access to the real arguments passed to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the calling arguments from the joinPoint:

```
@Around(.....)
public Object check(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    for (Object object : joinPoint.getArgs()) {
           .... add your checks here.
    }
    return joinPoint.proceed();

}
```

Note you can not easily get the name of the parameter from the joinPoint (like you can in .NET) but you could check on type and value.

See https://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/20/aspectj-cheat-sheet/ for valid execution patterns.

Comment: Also https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy I have changed my answer based on yours, so I've upvoted yours.

Comment: maybe I wrong but with `getArgs()` I have the parameters value, so I have to know the order

Comment: @luca yes you have to know what type or value you are looking for, you can not get the name.

Comment: (a) If you know where in the signature - counted from from left or right (1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.) - the parameter of interest is, you should use bind the value with `args()` instead of using the ugly `joinPoint.getArgs()` call with the surrounding loop. (b) I do not see what would be meaningful about parameter names which are subject to change by refactoring all the time, but if you absolutely want to, you can compile with `-parameters` and then get argument names via reflection. So the statement that it is not possible in Jave/AspectJ is false.

Comment: I hoped that the parameter annotation could provide the value of the parameter to avoid imposing the order of the parameters, so in my case there ins't difference between method and parameter annotation